# Get text from user and display it on page

Tags: custom-field, customization

I would like to ask you how can I go about getting text data from user and then displaying this custom per user text on their account page. Can I use custom fields for this?

Should I write my own plugin or something similar already exist?

I will appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your function php
past this code

```
function fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
?>
<h3><?php _e('Extra Profile Information', 'your_textdomain'); ?></h3>

<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="address"><?php _e('Address', 'your_textdomain'); ?>
        </label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'address', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e('Please enter your address.', 'your_textdomain'); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php }

function fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return FALSE;

update_usermeta( $user_id, 'address', $_POST['address'] );
}

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
```

this code will add Adress to profile fileds , just rename adress to what ever you want .

source http://wpengineer.com/2173/custom-fields-wordpress-user-profile/

Comment: Thank you very much! I dint expect to get full solution :)